# is it possible to combine files system from different servers and present it as one?

Tags: linux, unix, nfs

I have 3 physical servers (server01, server02 and server03) and local storage. I've created /app file system on all of three servers and mounted the storage there.

I need to be able to combine /app file system from 3 servers, and access it as one file system maybe called /total_app from server01.

Is this possible? How could I do this in linux OS.

Answer (score 6):

What you're likely looking for is called a *Distributed File System*. These require special handling and are not part of normal distro installations.

There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems) containing a non-exhaustive list of distributed file system platforms.

The main selling point of distributed file systems is redundancy, scalability, and access transparency.  Like RAID, enough data is generally replicated in order to survive one or more node outages. Also like RAID, the combined storage of multiple nodes is abstracted into a single storage volume. In most DFS systems, additional nodes can be added to increase the storage available without downtime or additional client configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for NFS. You can make server01 an NFS server that exports the /total_app directory. Then you can allow all servers to mount it. You must only be sure that server01 is always up, running, and accessible. Also be careful that the servers are not 'destroying' each other configurations for the applications in the directory.

Comment: @marko, I need to combine file systems called /app on 3 servers, into one file system and mount that final file system on one server only. Can nfs do this and how?

Comment: You mean something like a directory for each server in the `/total_app` directory? This is possible too. With NFS you can have any directory mounted on any server.

Comment: @marko, no. Let's say server01, 02, 03 all have local file system called /apps. I need to create a file system on server01 called /total_apps which will include server01:/apps, server01:/apps and server03:/apps.

Comment: Ah. The other way around. Would also be possible but this means that all servers must act as NFS server and allow server01 to mount their /app directory in /total_app. Why do you need this? Is it for maintaining the configuration 'on the fly'?

Comment: I only have 3 servers and need to combine the total storage on those servers. Curious, If I could use hbase and hdfs, but I only have 3 servers.

Comment: It is not clear. Will you have `/total_app/server01app`, `/total_app/server02app`, and `/total_app/server03app` to hold the `/app` of every server separately or just `/total_app` with everything put in there?

Comment: /total_app with everything put in there.